# Optimizing how to share style properties for all sibling components in react js

Tags: reactjs, textarea, mutation-observers

## What I'm trying to achieve

1. Have all of these `<textarea/>` components **share** the same `height` style.
2. If **ANY** of the `<textarea/>` element's **height style** changes, all of the `textareas` in the **same** row should have the same height.

[image]

## Current Working Solution

#### Parent component

*Lifting the state up, by having all the child components `share state`.*

```js
const TableRow = (props: TableRowProps) => {
  const [textAreaHeight, setTextAreaHeight] = useState<string>("100%");

  console.log("parent render");

  return (
    <tr>
      {props.currentRow.cells.map((rowValue) => (
        <DynamicCellTextArea
          key={rowValue.id}
          currentRow={rowValue}
          height={textAreaHeight}
          setHeight={setTextAreaHeight}
        />
      ))}
    </tr>
  );
};
```

#### Child component

*By using the `MutationObserver` to check if the `<textarea/>` element's style changed, THEN we'll set the state (height) variable so that it will reflect to **ALL** of `<textarea/>` elements in the whole **row**.*

```js
const DynamicCellTextArea = (props: DynamicCellTextAreaProps) => {
  const textareaRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (textareaRef.current === null) {
      return;
    }

    textareaRef.current.style.minWidth = "100%";
    textareaRef.current.style.minHeight = "100%";
    textareaRef.current.style.height = props.height;

    const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(() => {
      // set the height here so that child components (on the same row)
      // can have a shared height style (on state)
      props.setHeight(textareaRef.current?.style.height as string);
    });

    mutationObserver.observe(textareaRef.current, {
      attributes: true,
      attributeFilter: ["style"],
    });
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <td className="h-px border border-red-400 overflow">
      <div className="flex w-full h-full">
        <textarea
          ref={textareaRef}
          rows={1}
          className="w-full px-3 py-2 bg-red-500 resize"
        />
      </div>
    </td>
  );
}
```

## Performance issue with my solution

The rendering is *not smooth* especially if I have multiple columns and rows in my table (since it's going to be dynamic). I'm not sure how to optimize something like this. I tried to capture the resize of the textarea element (using `onResize` and `onResizeCapture`), then plan to `set the state` on those event/s. But I can't seem to do that.

*FULL CODE: https://github.com/paraJdox/table-rows-with-textarea-cells*

Comment: You can set `--height` variable on a parent's element `style` attribute so it'll apply to all children automatically and you won't need to observe it. Instead of setting `elem.style.height = foo` you would do `parentElem.style.setProperty('--height', foo)`

Comment: @wOxxOm, but then I need to have a **way** to check if the `textarea` (child element) changes its height style in order for all of the `textarea`s to have the same height. Without the `MutationObserver` the height that the `textarea`s will follow is the textarea with the greatest height.

Comment: It's probably okay because synchronous increasing of the height is what matters the most, as for decreasing I'd argue it must be delayed for better UX so I would do it after a delay in a listener for `input` event by applying a different css to the active textarea in order to unlink it from the common rule, then I'd calculate its real height and copy it into the --height var.